# Possible to host frontend on github and backend on Heroku?

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to host ones frontend code on github, and the backend code on Heroku ?

If it's possible, what do I need to know in order to accomplish it? (There doesn't seem to be any tutorials on this subject)

Comment: You'd create an API on Heroku and pull in the data with JS on your GitHub frontend. (React, Angular, Vue.js, etc can do this for you)

Comment: @NathanielSuchy Could you post an example on how you would pull the data from the frontend github?

Comment: Look over https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request use them to fetch data from an API hosted on Heroku. As for creating an API: https://www.restapitutorial.com/ writing the frontend code to use this API is on you. This is outside the scope of a single Stackoverflow answer, though you might find a blog post or two written on this topic. I don't like telling people to "Google it" however look across the web for tutorials for creating APIs and using them with frontend technology.